# Set a state variable to every page

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

On every page, I do this function:

```
import * as sync_helper from '../utils/sync';

componentWillUnmount() { this._isMounted = false; }
componentDidMount() {

  this._isMounted = true;

  sync_helper.getLocal().then((l) => {

    if(this._isMounted)
      this.setState({ current_user: l.current_user,loaded: true });

  });
}
```

I also sometimes have a lot more async functions in the `componentDidMount()` but this one is in EVERY page.

Is there a way to automatically add my `current_user` to every state without putting this on every page?

I'm using React Navigation (Stacks)

Comment: React Contexts? https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: @Chris is this a thing on react-native?

Comment: I haven't used it with `react-native` but I believe it is present there too.